# WPF with datagrid to delete selected items

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I have a Datagrid that get filled from a SQLite table

```
Connect();
mAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM clients", mConn);
mTable = new DataTable();
mAdapter.Fill(mTable);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = mTable.DefaultView;
mConn.Close();
```

I can make it delete an selecteditem but how can I make it delete selecteditems based on their id

```
private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete)
        {
            if (dataGrid.SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
            Connect();
            using (SQLiteCommand mCmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM clients WHERE ID=" + rowView["ID"], mConn))
            {
                mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            mAdapter.Update(mTable);
            mConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code should works and delete based on `id`. What's your problem?

Comment: I want to delete multiple items but I can't figure out how to get all the items IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use raw query to delete the items. In this case to access the selected items on the DataGrid, you use the property `SelectedItems`. You can either delete each one with 1 query or a block of items in 1 query, here is the code to delete each one using 1 query:

```
if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete) {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        Connect();
        foreach(var item in dataGrid.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>()) {
           using (var mCmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM clients WHERE ID=" + item["ID"], mConn)) {
              mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
        }
        mAdapter.Update(mTable);
        mConn.Close();
}
```

Here is the code to delete a block of items with 1 query:

```
if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete) {
        if (dataGrid.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
        Connect();
        const int blockSize = 100;
        var inOperands = dataGrid.SelectedItems
                                 .Select((e,i) => new { 
                                    row = ((DataRowView) e)["ID"], i        
                                  })
                                 .GroupBy(e => e.i / blockSize)
                                 .Select(g => string.Format("({0})", 
                                              string.Join(",", g.Select(o => o.row))));
        foreach(var inOperand in inOperands) {
           using (var mCmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM clients WHERE ID IN " + inOperand, mConn)) {
              mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
        }
        mAdapter.Update(mTable);
        mConn.Close();
}
```

By the way you should use `SQLiteParameter` rather than concatenate the values manually to avoid query injection.

Comment: thanks for help but there isn't any "cast" for the "datagrid.selecteditems" maybe it's for Windows forms and I use WPF
for the query injection I just make this program for training to use new stuff I will not use it in a real program but again thanks for mention it

Comment: @AhmedMohammed you need to add using `System.Linq;`, it's a feature of Linq supported by the static class `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

As user2946329 said your code should work. I think if you need to delete multiple items you need more buttons and you have to set each button to delete through separate variables or you can loop through them via the actual sql data e.g.

```
string a = select name, from tbl where name = "Ahmed" 
string b =       select name, from tbl where name = "Ahmed"etc)
```

then just

```
SQLiteCommand mCmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM clients WHERE ID=" + a + b, mConn))
        {
            mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Yes I want to delete multiple items that I select from the datagrid but I can't figure out how to get all the items IDs to use them at my SQLite command

Comment: Are the items physical keyboard buttons or just data from the db?

Comment: I filled the datagrid with data from the database the user is able to multi select items from that datagrid and delete them and when he does I want to delete the same data from the db based on their IDs

Comment: I hope this worked. But if it doesn't please try King King's suggestions. Ta